# To make the effect work separately for each class (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

There are three classes named "main-menu."
I want to apply the effect that underlines when I raise the mouse cursor in the area corresponding to each class.
I know that the current target is in the 0th index of the class and I have to use variables, but I don't know how to change that to suit the situation.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this problem.

[image]

```
window.onload = function(){
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("main-menu")[0];
target.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    target.style.borderBottom = "5px solid black";
});
target.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    target.style.borderBottom = "none";
});
```

}

Comment: Are all main-menu elements fall under a common parent? If yes, just select the parent element -> addEventListener -> define available object to react to (event delegation) -> access defined target and apply CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding mouse hover css instead

```
.main-menu:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop and add effect to each element. You can do this with css as well

`.main-menu:hover { border-bottom: 5px solid black; }`

```js
    window.onload = function(){
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("main-menu");

for(let index=0; index < elements.length;index++) {
  const target = elements[index];
  target.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      target.style.borderBottom = "5px solid black";
  });
  target.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      target.style.borderBottom = "none";
  });
})
}
```